# Single-line TextBox overflow unscrollable

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, textbox

Not sure if this is a bug or what, but none of my TextBoxes allow horizontal scrolling. I've tried various ways to resolve, but nothing's a winner yet. To be specific, I want to be ability to select text and drag left/right to show overflow.

I first started off by removing any styles targeting the TextBox.

Then I added some properties like `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=Visible, VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Disabled, AcceptsReturn=False, TextWrapping=NoWrap`...

So far, adding any of the above properties does nothing.

Is there a property I'm missing or an event handler I need to add for this?

**Edit**

Forgot to mention, the actual scroll bar shows (horizontal), but it doesn't allow you to drag selected text left/right. I just removed a style that targets ScrollBar, but that doesn't seem to be getting in the way.

**Edit 2**

Simple example:

```
<TextBox
    Text="Lots of text to cause overflow"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    AcceptsReturn="False"
    TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
```

[image: example]

**Edit 3**

The issue is stemming from a style I use to target ScrollViewer, though I'm not sure the cause:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                    <!--<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Red"/>-->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Edit 4**

As per Sakura's suggestion, I have:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ScrollBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
        <ScrollBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But it's still not working...

Comment: Added an example in original post.

Comment: Your above code is not real XAML code. There is no `TextWrap` attribute of `TextBox`.

Comment: Typo, should be `TextWrapping`.

Comment: You can not drag text left-right, but you still can select text, right?

Comment: I can select text, but I can't drag the selection left/right to see the overflow. I basically want to scroll horizontally without the horizontal scroll bar and by dragging selected text.

Comment: could you create new WPF project and copy the textbox XAML alone to that project to see if problem still occur? Your above code don't say you do anything wrong.

Comment: Yes, oddly enough, doing that it works. I found an article here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356654/textbox-can-not-drag-select-text, where someone also apparently had this issue because they made their form a dockable container. Unfortunately for me, I'm not using Windows Forms and I have not made my window a dockable container.

Comment: Then the error is somewhere other in the code. If you can do following action, people can find problem for you: copy current project, in copied project, you remove everything until the error disappear, then add back the last part that cause problem, then you can post full XAML here. Your current code is too little info

Comment: @Sakura use Snoop (or VS2015's inspector) to inspect the Visual Tree and make sure the ScrollViewer is getting the proper property values.

Comment: I can not tell anything. If you can provide minimal code example (can be a zip file contain a cut-down version of working project) that we can run and reproduce the problem, only then we can tell what is wrong with your code

Comment: @HighCore it not my problem with `TextBox` but the asker's problem :)

Comment: Jackpot! Turns out it was a style I made targeting ScrollViewer. I will post the full code for that above in another edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `ScrollViewer` style auto set for your `TextBox`. You can test it by change `<Grid>` to `<Grid Background="Yellow">` at the style.

You override it but don't set `CanContentScroll="True"` to the `ScrollContentPresenter`.

Change:

```
<ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

To:

```
<ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="True"/>
```

Comment: So how do I modify the ScrollViewer style so it doesn't cut off the overflow? I realized the reason I put this style there in the first place was because my style targeting ScrollBar would leave a white, perfectly-shaped square in the bottom right corner of the ScrollViewer, so the need for it is crucial. Targeting all of them prevents the need to add the style manually to each one, which, given the number I have, would be a pain to have to go through and add/manage.

Comment: @kill4silence just change `<ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>` to `<ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="True"/>`